# array one value should pass each time and here passing all the values

Tags: shell

In the below bash script all values are passing in one time.

But I need each time one value should pass then iteration should happen, next time one more value should pass.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a CWA=$(cat /tmp/file)
read -a ${CWA[@]}
CWA_COUNT=$(cat /tmp/file|wc -l)
COUNT=1
while [ "$COUNT" -le "$CWA_COUNT" ]
do
echo "AWS Cloudwatch StatusCheckFailed alram set -$COUNT"
touch ${CWA[@]}
COUNT="`expr $COUNT + 1`"
done
```

Comment: Hi & Welcome to stackoverflow ! You should try to explicit what the issue is, it is currently quite unclear of what you looking help with :/ You may wanna have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some pro-tips about formatting/asking questions :-)

Comment: cat /tmp/file 
apple1
apple2
apple3
apple4
apple5